# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for Employee

Tags: python, django

I am trying to extend the user model

so I created a new model called employee with foreignkey to user model

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and tried to create a form for the signup

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from employee.models import Employee

class EmployeeForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = Employee
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('department',)
```

These are the only changes I made I am getting the following error:

> File "/home/sugumar/python/django/project1/project1/urls.py", line
>   18, in 
>       from employee.views import signup   File "/home/sugumar/python/django/project1/employee/views.py", line 2, in
>   
>       from .forms import EmployeeForm   File "/home/sugumar/python/django/project1/employee/forms.py", line 4, in
>   
>       class EmployeeForm(UserCreationForm):   File "/home/sugumar/.local/share/virtualenvs/project1-j0yhUYNK/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py",
>   line 266, in **new**
>       raise FieldError(message) django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for Employee

Comment: You can not inherit fields like that, an `Employee` has no `username`. I think the smallest change is to use *two* forms, and thus render it as one, and then handle both forms, and construct a `User` and `Employee` object.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, so there is no way to add custom fields to existing forms, right?

Comment: there is, you can simply add fields to your form, but that will not make a "binding" to the model fields (which is after all the convenience a `ModelForm` offers most people are interested in).

Comment: Sorry to bump an old question but I'm having a similar issue -- is there no way to bind custom `User` form fields to custom `User` model fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am trying to extend the user model, so I created a new model called employee with foreignkey to user model.

By using a `OneToOneField`, one *can* indeed extend the user system, but you can not simply use this to handle both models in the same `Form`, and thus construct two objects at once.

What you here basically construct is a `ModelForm` on the `Employee` model, but here you have constructed a `Meta` class with extra fields, but these fields are not related to model fields on the `Employee` object, hence the error.

Probably it is better to simply construct two forms, so the `Employee`-form looks like:

```
# app/forms.py

from django.forms import ModelForm

class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('department',)
```

and then create a view like:

```
# app/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from app.forms import EmployeeForm

def create_user(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        employee_form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and employee_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            employee = employee_form.save(commit=False)
            employee.user = user
            employee.save()
            return redirect('...')
    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
        employee_form = EmployeeForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'app/my_template.html',
        {'user_form': user_form, 'employee_form': employee_form}
    )
```

In the view we will thus, given both forms are valid, create a `User` and `Employee` object and link the `employee` to the `user`. We furthermore render the template with two forms.

In the template, we render the two forms in the same `<form>` tag:

```
<!-- app/templates/app/my_template.html -->

<form action="{% url 'app:create_user' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form }}
    {{ employee_form }}
</form>
```

Where `'app:create_user'` is the name of the URL that points to the view defined above.

Comment: Awesome, Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I solved it deleting all the references to Employee. Then:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

And finally adding Employee and finishing the migration:

```
python manage.py makemigrations        
python manage.py migrate
```